# Join Query relational data

Tags: sql-server

can you help me?

Sample Data:

[image]

Desc:

```
  TableA is =IDAPK, No Urut(L1), No Tampil (L1), Text Faktor (L1)

  TableB is =IDBPK, IDAFK, No Urut(L2), No Tampil (L2), Text Faktor (L2)

  IDAPK=IDAFK (ForeignKkey)
```

Can you join make query with SQL Server to be like the result in a picture above? I can't find my logic.
Thank You...

Comment: The type of formatting you want would probably be handled best in your presentation layer.  Are you expecting a raw query to generate that output, or are you using another language?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Query...

Comment: What reporting tool are you using? Or are you just exporting to a CSV or something? What query have you tried so far? Why does it need to be presented in that way - is it for an end user?

Comment: not CSV bro, i want query which result like a picture above. this picture just sample. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: You need a tool to convert a SQL statement into a picture. For example you could run a query in SSMS and then take a screenshot - is that what you want to do? You need to specify what tool you are creating this 'picture' in. If it is SSMS then we can build a query that does something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to do that. Two `query` from two `table` then `Union All` those `result`. Check below SQL:

```
Select [No Urut(L1)],[No Tampil (L1)],[Text Faktor (L1)],[No Urut(L2)],[No Tampil (L2)],[Text Faktor (L2)] From
(
    Select IDAPK As ID,1 As SL,[No Urut(L1)],[No Tampil (L1)],[Text Faktor (L1)],'' As [No Urut(L2)],'' As [No Tampil (L2)], '' As [Text Faktor (L2)] From TableA
        Union All
    Select IDAFK As ID,2 As SL,'' As [No Urut(L1)],'' As [No Tampil (L1)],'' As [Text Faktor (L1)],[No Urut(L2)],[No Tampil (L2)],[Text Faktor (L2)] From TableB
) As TableAB Order By ID, SL
```

Output the SQL:

[image]

Comment: You also need to add an `order by` to that as order is not guaranteed without an order by

Comment: bro IDAPK is belong TableA not TableB.. TableB is IDAFK ..thank you @csharpbd

Answer (score 0):

This query uses INNER JOIN so it returns records that have matching values in both tables.

```
SELECT TableA.[No Urut(L1)], TableA.[No Tampil (L1)], TableA.[Text Faktor (L1)], TableB.[No Urut(L2)], TableB.[No Tampil (L2)], TableB.[Text Faktor (L2)]
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.IDPK=TableB.IDFK;
```